# Photo organiser app

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, photos

What app would you propose to my father (simple HCI) who wants to sort, organise and attribute details to his pictures; which are taken or downloaded.

Main aspects of the app is to organise easily or automatically and to set metadata to the pics so he can remember the details.

I tried the Photo Investigator app but I was disappointed by the way you set the caption image details and messes with your photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Pixave](http://www.pixaveapp.com/) 2. It's a photo organizer/viewer that features auto import, extensive tagging, multiple libraries, web capture, and an awesome UI. I switched to it from Photos and I'm very happy with the experience so far.

Comment: Thanks this look cool, however, I found it only for MAC, is there an ipad version?

Comment: They're working on an iOS version right now. :-)